# Why are the trucks getting stuck in front of my prison?

Tags: prison-architect

I'm having some trouble with the trucks that deliver prisoners and items in *Prison Architect*. They are all stuck on the road, not moving and no ingredients can get to my cooks. My prisoners are rioting ... which is a bit unpleasant.

Here is a screenshot of the problem:
[image: Screenshot]

Is it just an Alpha bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It's working fine now the fencing is gone. Thanks!

Comment: Comment turned into an answer.

Answer (score 10):

For a delivery area to be considered valid - and thus a stop for the truck - it has to be connected to the curb of the road. (That is, one square to the left from the actual road.)

Your fenced-off delivery area is in a valid position and therefore the truck stops there to be unloaded. The workers, however, cannot access the truck, as the position next to the truck is blocked by the fence.

If you remove the fence, your truck should be accessible and unloaded appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Also, check if aren't any small delivery areas. I mucked about with the different areas but a 3 tile big delivery area was still there. But it was filled up with random supplies so I didn't see the words and the driver couldn't unload. (Because the area was full.)

Answer (score -1):

You can also fix that by editing the save file after the days in game save. Important: if you cant find it that stucked truck, you must wait until the next day auto save. You need count the truck after another truck is coming until you find the corret one. Then you delete it and save it. Then open it justnow save file, and you will see that truck is gone.(This idea is very useful I have use justnow)